# C# Oracle Displaying data set in a data grid

Tags: c#, oracle

I am trying to get a query from Oracle to display inside a data grid view in Visual Studio, but when I run the program I only get horizontal lines inside the data grid view, I'm not sure where I am going wrong?

```
        //declarations
        //declare sql string
        String strSQL, conString;
        String dateStart = startDate.ToString(dateFormat), dateEnd = endDate.ToString(dateFormat);

        //SQL string
        strSQL = "SELECT TO_CHAR(V.CASEID) AS CASEID, V.MESSAGESET, V.LOCALMESSAGETIME, V.TEXT";
        strSQL = strSQL + " FROM OPR.V_MKTVALIDATIONMESSAGE V, OPR.MKTCASE C";
        strSQL = strSQL + " WHERE V.LOCALMESSAGETIME >= to_date('" + dateStart + "','MM/DD/YYYY hh24')";
        strSQL = strSQL + " AND V.LOCALMESSAGETIME < to_date('" + dateEnd + "','MM/DD/YYYY hh24')";
        strSQL = strSQL + " AND V.CASEID IS NOT NULL";
        strSQL = strSQL + " AND V.CASEID = C.CASEID";
        strSQL = strSQL + " AND MESSAGESET = 'EXPORTER'";
        strSQL = strSQL + " AND C.STUDYMODEID in (32)";
        strSQL = strSQL + " AND (TEXT LIKE 'SCP%Begin exporting%' OR TEXT LIKE 'SCP%Export           completed%' OR TEXT LIKE 'ANS%Begin exporting%' OR TEXT LIKE 'ANS%Export completed%' OR TEXT LIKE 'SCD%Begin exporting%' OR TEXT LIKE 'SCD%Export completed%')";
        strSQL = strSQL + " ORDER BY CASEID, V.LOCALMESSAGETIME ASC";


        //setup the connection string aka username, password, and database to connect to
        conString = "Data Source=OPRPRD;User ID=" + userN + ";Password = " + pass + ";Unicode=True";

        //create connection object
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(conString);

        //open connection
        con.Open();

        //decalare oracle connection
        OracleCommand ocom = new OracleCommand();

        //assign connection to command
        ocom.Connection = con;

        //assign command string to oracle command
        ocom.CommandText = strSQL;

        OracleDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter();

        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = ocom;

        dataAdapter.Fill(ds, "itscedExportTable");
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", ds.Tables.ToString());
        dataGrid1.DataContext = ds;
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = "itscedExportTable";


        con.Close();
```

Comment: You're not typing in a DB at the moment, turn off caps lock. =)

Comment: Why are you screaming at us? We only want to help.